# Gradle - how to iterate in fileTree only for certain type of file

Tags: gradle, filetree

in my gradle task I iterate through fileTree and all works good:

```
myTask {
  fileTree("${project.projectDir}/dir").visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
    exec {
      //do some operations
    }
  }
}
```

but now I have different types of files in my directory:

```
dir
├── sub1
│   ├── file1.json
│   └── file2.js
├── sub2
│   ├── file1.json
│   └── file2.js
└── sub3
    ├── file1.js
    └── file2.json
```

How to iterate for only certain type of files? Because

```
"${project.projectDir}/folder/dir/**/*.json"
```

doesnt work.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [`matching`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html#matching-groovy.lang.Closure-) method from `FileTree`. It uses a [`PatternFilterable`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html) as parameter.

Try that :

```
fileTree("${project.projectDir}/dir").matching {
    include "**/*.json"
}.each {
    // do some operations
}
```

Comment: With some changes: `fileTree("${project.projectDir}/dir/").matching {
    include "**/*.json"
  }.visit  { FileVisitDetails details ->
    exec {
     //do some operations
    }` it works! :) Thanks for help